# File Open dialog box not closing in puppeteer automation

Tags: javascript, file-upload, jestjs, puppeteer

UploadFile function not closing the File open dialog box.I tried the following script but that is not working.

```
page.on('filedialog', async input => {
  await input.uploadFile('./foo.jpg')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `filedialog` event. To fill a `<input type="file" .../>` field, you just use the [`elementHandle.uploadFile`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#elementhandleuploadfilefilepaths) function like this:

```js
const input = await page.$('input[name=...]'); // get element handle via selector
await input.uploadFile('path/to/file.txt');
```

You do not need to click the input field or wait for an event to trigger before filling in the file.

Comment: How do you close the dialog though? In headless: false it never closes.

Comment: @chovy You cannot close the dialog. Don't open the dialog and use `uploadFile` instead.

Comment: @chovy Please read the answer. If the question (and answer) do not apply to your case, open a new question.